# With Rails 5, how to validate a param is a valid email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an invites controller which gets a array of params posted with emails... I want to ensure the emails received by the controller are validated as emails before the emails are stored in the database.

I'm planning to validate in the controller, if that's incorrect, please let me know.

Does Rails 5 have a built-in method to validate emails or are Rails 5 developers dependent on a GEM for validating an email address?

Comment: that is an answer years old and from Rails 3... not at all a a duplicate.

Comment: Some things don't age. This is one of them.